# JavaScript Processing In Selenium And HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, htmlunit

I'm planning to use HtmlUnit in my Java application to test drive some website but I heard it may not be able to handle complex JavaScript, what is your experience with the level of complex JavaScript that both HtmlUnit and Selenium can handle?

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried it out briefly, and in my experience it breaks on ANY javascript error that the IE javascript engine would throw.

Comment: My experience is similar to RedDeckWins. If you already have JS code, then HtmlUnit will drive you crazy. If you are planning to write that JS your own then you'll have to do it the way HtmlUnit wants. However, I think HtmlUnit is quite fast regarding JS. So probably, if speed is critical, then it might be a good option.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "complex"... I've had no problems testing sites using JQuery or Yahoo JS libraries.

Comment: In my past experience, that depends on your javascript as well, most of the problems I had was Ajax related issue. But normal javascript I think it should be fine.